# Error in java package

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
@Test

private void AutoItTest() throws IOException {
   java.lang.Runtime().getRuntime().exec("C:\\Selenium\\framework\\AutoITpopupHandler.exe");
}
```

Error prompted at java.lang Please provide an appropriate solution.

Comment: What kind of error is shown?

Answer (score 5):

`Runtime` is a class, you don't "call" it. It should be like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Selenium\\framework\\AutoITpopupHandler.exe");
```

Qualifying with `java.lang` is also not needed, but won't hurt anything.